# create oracle table rows from date range

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a table which has column for storing date

```
STARTDATE  |  ENDDATE
01/04/2018 |  05/04/2018
07/04/2018 |  08/04/2018
```

I want to write a simple query which can give me result.

```
DATE
01/04/2018
02/04/2018
03/04/2018
04/04/2018
05/04/2018
07/04/2018
08/04/2018
```

is this is possible by oracle?

Comment: yes its possible by SQL. Have you tried writing a query yourself ?

Comment: This is covered in many places, including elsewhere on SO and in the Oracle docs.  Have you tried something yet?

Comment: i tried by searching but not able to find any reference, do you a link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle dates support arithmetic operations. So `sysdate+1` is tomorrow.

We can generate rows using [Oracle's hierarchical syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/queries003.htm#SQLRF52332), CONNECT BY. The pseudo-column LEVEL gives us the increment we need.

The tricky part is working with multiple rows from a table. The CONNECT BY will generate a product unless we can tie the generated rows to their PRIOR rows. Ideally the source table has a primary key we can use as an anchor; your posted table lacks one of these, but we can substitute ROWID instead.

```
select startdate + (level-1) as gendate
from t23
connect by level <= (enddate-startdate)+1
            and t23.rowid = prior t23.rowid
            and prior sys_guid() is not null
order by 1
```

The `and prior sys_guid() is not null` is not intuitive, but it's there to prevent `ORA-01436: CONNECT BY loop in user data`.

Here is [a SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e252fd/1).